# Proof of the Darboux's Theorem by Lars Olsen

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to follow the proof of the Darboux's Theorem presented by Lars Olsen.

**Darboux's Theorem.** Let $I$ be an open interval, and let $f:I\to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. If $a$ and $b$ are points in $I$ with $a\leq b$ and if $y$ lies between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$, then there exists $x$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f'(x)=y$.

He started his proof with the following.

Assume that $y$ lies strictly between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$. Define $f_a,f_b:I\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f_a(t)=
\begin{cases}
f'(a), &\mbox{ for } t=a\\
\displaystyle{\frac{f(a)-f(t)}{a-t}}, &\mbox{ for }t\neq a
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f_b(t)=
\begin{cases}
f'(b), &\mbox{ for } t=b\\
\displaystyle{\frac{f(t)-f(b)}{t-b}}, &\mbox{ for }t\neq b.
\end{cases}
$$
I can verify that $f_a$ and $f_b$ are continuous on $[a,b]$ and that $f_a(a)=f'(a)$, $f_a(b)=f_b(a)$, and $f_b(b)=f'(b)$.

**Question.** Why is it that $y$ lies between $f_a(a)$ and $f_a(b)$ or $y$ lies between $f_b(a)$ and $f_b(b)$?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: By the way, this proof also appears in Mathematical Analysis (2 ed., 1974) by Tom Apostol. Thus the title of Olsen's paper (A New Proof of Darboux's Theorem) is not really true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assume that $y$ lies between $A$ and $B$. Now you introduce some other point $C$ and conclude that $y$ may lie between $A$ and $C$ or between $C$ and $B$.

Or put another way, the segment $AB$ is a subset of the union of the segments $AC$ and $CB$, and that holds even if $C$ lies outside $AB$.

Comment: Thank you. I got what you mean. The point $C$ refers to $f_a(b)$, of which I'm confused whether it is in between $f_a(a)$ and $f_b(b)$.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. We do not need to force the situation above.  Thank you very much.